# Can I use EF4 with sp_msforeachdb?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-4

I have a query simplified version:

```
declare @s nvarchar(max)
set @s ='
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted
select
      [db] = cast(specific_catalog as varchar(30))
      ,[num_procs] = count(*) 
      ,[len_procs] = sum(len(routine_definition)) 
from
      ?.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
where
      ROUTINE_TYPE=''PROCEDURE''
group by
      specific_catalog'

exec sp_msforeachdb @s
```

Can I consume this via a strongly typed EF4 object? It's been awhile since I came across something that has me thinking I have to go back to regular ADO, but I'm not sure how to tackle this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO this is something which should be executed as stored procedure by common ADO.NET. Why:

- It is SQL command which cannot be mapped as entity
- It returns multiple result sets - stored procedures in EF are not able to map multiple result sets even it returns still the same object. There was available [extensions for EFv1](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EFExtensions) which added that support but still it is somthing unsure.